# My Hello World does run, but only shortly - Android

Tags: android

all I am doing:

Eclipse --> new Project --> Android Application --> Activity type: blank

no changes in the code, just the simple Hello world.

It does start, I see the Hello World on the virtual device, but then immediately shuts down.

The `logcat` is as follows:

```
 08-31 06:01:14.976: W/dalvikvm(1114): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught          exception(group=0xb2aeeba8)
08-31 06:01:14.996: E/AndroidRuntime(1114): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-31 06:01:14.996: E/AndroidRuntime(1114): Process: com.example.tester, PID: 1114
08-31 06:01:14.996: E/AndroidRuntime(1114): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:    android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable
08-31 06:01:14.996: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at   android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:107)
```

Any Ideas?

Edit:

Ok, apparently I for some reason have a dependency mixup:

```
    Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
    [2014-08-31 12:22:46 - tester] but not all the versions are identical (check is    based on SHA-1 only at this
```

Can I simply delete one of them?

Comment: It seems that the appcompat library has not been properly added.

Answer (score 1):

The error is essentially telling you that it can't find the Android Support Library, which it is using as a dependency.

Without knowing what build process you're using (e.g gradle) it's difficult to tell you how to fix it, but basically you'll need to either add it as a dependency, or remove the code that requires it.

For more information on the Android Support Library, try this:

https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

Comment: This, however, does not seem to make any difference

Comment: If you've added it, and you're still getting the error message, the most likely scenario is that it just isn't being picked up by the build process. Are you using Gradle? How did you add it as a dependency? Do you get the same error message without the library added? All these would be useful details to have.

Comment: I have no Idea what gradle is - I added it in eclipse by clicking on  tools--> add. and yes, the error message remains the same.

Comment: can be closed - for some reason as yet unknown to me the problem was solved by the simple measure of restarting eclipse

Answer (score 0):

If do not work the try this :

**Step #1:** Undo all that. If you are messing with the build path, on R16 or higher version of the ADT plugin for Eclipse, you're doing it wrong.

**Step #2:** Pick one of those two versions of the JAR, or pick the one from the "extras" area of your SDK installation.

**Step #3**: Put the right JAR in App Library.

**Step #4:** Delete the one from App Free, since it will pick up that JAR from App Library.